# Save a list in a text file

Tags: java, file, text, text-files

I'm doing a simple study planner and I'm doing a simple user login system.
So far I've did that when the user registers it is saved in a text file named as the username of whom registered.  The login part also worked.  Now I want that when the user registers another frame (`subjectFrame`) opens.  In this frame the user inputs the subjects.

When he presses done I want to save the list in a text file called `username + "subjects"`.
How can I get the username registered before?

Answer (score 0):

`when the user registers it is saved in a textfile named as the username of whom registered`

How are you getting the user name is this case? The same way you can get username when saving subject details.

When user logs in, save the username for complete session until user logs out.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to store the subjects and the username in the same file. If so, what you could do is wait until the end of the program output to the text file. Just store the username in a local variable, and then use the same idea in the subject frame. Lastly, before the program exits, just output both fields to the text file in whatever format you want.